# 500 server error as soon as the namespace part of the docusign PHP SDK example is reached

Tags: php, docusignapi

I get a 500 server error when running the docusign php sdk example code.

I've ensured that I am using a PHP version above the required version. I am using PHP v 5.3.5, and the required version is 5.3.3. I have also ensured that curl and json are enabled. I have cut the example code listed on the github down to just these few lines, and still get the error. When I comment out the part that uses name spacing, the error stops occurring.

```
<?
    require_once( 'includes/docusign-php-client-master/autoload.php' );

    class DocuSign {

        private $config;

        public function __construct( $email, $password, $integratorKey ) {
            // error happens on next line
            $this->config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
        }
    }

    $docusign = new DocuSign( $myemail, $mypassword, $myintegrationkey );
?>
```

I have replaced my actual email, pass, and key with variables. Any ideas as to why I am getting the error?

Comment: You have `short tags` enabled in your server...if not, replace the first `<?` with `<?php `

Comment: @Hackerman added 'php', this did not stop the server 500 error. as I mentioned, commenting out the one line that uses name spacing stops all errors, so the short tag is not causing the error.

Comment: Are you on a Linux machine?..can you open a terminal and write the following command `tail -f /var/logs/httpd.log`, check your php file again and look at what gets logged in the apache log.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the required PHP version listed on the SDK is wrong. The SDK uses the array creation shorthand `[]`, which requires PHP version 5.4 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, error 500 will often happen if newly uploaded files don't have the appropriate permissions on the server. Apply appropriate `chmod` permissions from the bash console (or FTP server) to allow Apache to read the files.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not what is causing the error.